# Do i need the soft keyboard .java files in project?

Tags: android

I've copied the soft keyboard .java files into my project. I've got the keyboard to pop up in my view, but something tells me that i don't need the keyboard src files directly in my project unless I want to change the keyboard. I've commented out some of these files and the keyboard still pops up. do you just use the keyboard like any other class that ships with android.

```
public void record() {
            int frequency = 44100;
            int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
            int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/reverseme.pcm");

        // Delete any previous recording.
        if (file.exists())
        file.delete();


        // Create the new file.
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create " + file.toString());
        }

        try {
        // Create a DataOuputStream to write the audio data into the saved file.
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        // Create a new AudioRecord object to record the audio.
        //int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        frequency, channelConfiguration,
        audioEncoding, bufferSize);

        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        audioRecord.startRecording();


        while (isRecording) {
        int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++)
        dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
        }




        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AudioRecord","Recording Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        im.showSoftInput(this.findViewById(R.id.editText1), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are using a [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), The keyboard will automatically popup when you tap on it to edit.

You need not port your own version of soft qwerty

To show :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
InputMethodManager ipmgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And to hide:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
ipmgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

So i think you are on the right track.

Comment: ok thanks. are there any good example out there that show a simple set up for a qwerty keyboard. I've got an app that records audio samples and once the recording is finished i'd like the keyboard to pop up so the user can specify a file name. I'm new to android and i've had a look at the keyboard samples on the android site, but they are a little hard to digest at the moment. I've ammended orig post